# Split Address Column value using regular expression in snowflake sql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There is Column in snowflake table named Address. need to split that columns in to multiple columns.
below is sample regular expression used in one of python code.

```
apt_pattern = r'(?i)(?P<StreetNum>[0-9]+)(?P<StreetName>.*)\s(?P<UnitType>APT|#|UNIT|NBR|STE|SUITE|BLDG|BUILDING)\s(?P<Unit>.*)$'
```

Like wise need to split Address column in StreetNum,StreetName,UnitType,Unit using snowflake SQL

below is sample data,

| Address |
| --- |
| 616 NE CHERY DR UNIT A1008 |
| 740 NE 3RD ST # 3-1999 |
| 13456 SW HAKS BTPD ST APT 1052 |
| 460 MAIN ST BUILDING C STE 480 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR function to extract the subgroups from the matched expression:

```
select 
REGEXP_SUBSTR( address, '([0-9]+) (.*) (APT|#|UNIT|NBR|STE|SUITE|BLDG|BUILDING) (.*)',1,1,'e',1 ) StreetNum,
REGEXP_SUBSTR( address, '([0-9]+) (.*) (APT|#|UNIT|NBR|STE|SUITE|BLDG|BUILDING) (.*)',1,1,'e',2 ) StreetName,
REGEXP_SUBSTR( address, '([0-9]+) (.*) (APT|#|UNIT|NBR|STE|SUITE|BLDG|BUILDING) (.*)',1,1,'e',3 ) UnitType,
REGEXP_SUBSTR( address, '([0-9]+) (.*) (APT|#|UNIT|NBR|STE|SUITE|BLDG|BUILDING) (.*)',1,1,'e',4 ) Unit
from values 
('616 NE CHERY DR UNIT A1008'),
('740 NE 3RD ST # 3-1999'),
('13456 SW HAKS BTPD ST APT 1052'),
('460 MAIN ST BUILDING C STE 480') tmp (address);

+-----------+--------------------+----------+--------+
| STREETNUM |     STREETNAME     | UNITTYPE |  UNIT  |
+-----------+--------------------+----------+--------+
|       616 | NE CHERY DR        | UNIT     | A1008  |
|       740 | NE 3RD ST          | #        | 3-1999 |
|     13456 | SW HAKS BTPD ST    | APT      | 1052   |
|       460 | MAIN ST BUILDING C | STE      | 480    |
+-----------+--------------------+----------+--------+
```

REGEXP_SUBSTR https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html